# how to count the number of relation i a ManyToMany relation and order by it, TypeOrm and NestJs

Tags: typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I'm struggling to determine the correct approach for sorting the team entity based on the count of its followers.

this is my Team Entity :

```
      @Entity()
        export class Team extends CustomBaseEntity {
          @Column({
            nullable: true,
          })
          ....

         @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.followed_teams)
         @ApiHideProperty()
          followers: User[];

          ...
        }
```

and this my User Entity :

```
@Entity()
            export class User extends CustomBaseEntity {
              @Column({
                nullable: true,
              })
              ....

              @ManyToMany(() => Team, (team) => team.followers)
              @JoinTable({ name: 'user_followed_teams' })
              @ApiProperty()
               followed_teams: Team[] ;

              ...
            }
```

this is what I tried so far :

```
public findAll(query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<Team>> {
    const teamWithFollowerCount = this.teamRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('team')
      .select((subQuery) => {
        return subQuery
          .select('COUNT(follower.id)', 'followerCount')
          .from(User, 'follower')
          .leftJoin('follower.followed_teams', 'followed_team')
          .where('followed_team.id = team.id')
          .groupBy('followed_team.id');
      }, 'followerCount')
      .orderBy('followerCount', 'DESC');
    return paginate(query, teamWithFollowerCount, teams_pagination_config);
  }
```

and it arises this error :

> column followerCount doesn't exist

I tried :

```
   .createQueryBuilder('team')
   .loadRelationCountAndMap('team.followerCount', 'team.followers')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('team.followers', 'followers')
   .orderBy('team.followerCount', 'DESC')
```

it arises the same error

and this :

```
      .createQueryBuilder('team')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('team.followers', 'follower')
      .addSelect('COUNT(follower.id)', 'followerCount')
      .groupBy('team.id')
      .addGroupBy('follower.id')
      .orderBy('followerCount', 'DESC');
```

hope someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the counting and ordering based on a ManyToMany relationship in TypeORM within a NestJS application, you should be able to utilize a subquery with correct aliasing and referencing. The method involves joining the intermediary table, counting the relations, and then ordering by that count. It’s critical that your subquery returns a numeric value for the followerCount to be sortable.

Here’s a modified version of your approach that should work:

```
public findAll(query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<Team>> {
  const teamWithFollowerCount = this.teamRepo
    .createQueryBuilder('team')
    .leftJoin('team.followers', 'follower')
    .loadRelationCountAndMap('team.followerCount', 'team.followers')
    .addSelect(subQuery => {
      return subQuery
        .select('COUNT(follower_sub.id)', 'followerCount')
        .from(User, 'follower_sub')
        .leftJoin('follower_sub.followed_teams', 'followed_team_sub')
        .where('followed_team_sub.id = team.id')
    }, 'followerCount') // This is our subquery to count the followers
    .groupBy('team.id') // Need to group by to aggregate, i.e., count the followers
    .orderBy('followerCount', 'DESC'); // Order by the count we obtained
  
  return paginate(query, teamWithFollowerCount, teams_pagination_config);
}
```

Ensure that you indeed use the proper configuration for pagination, which can handle additional selected columns.
Verify that the resultant SQL from TypeORM is valid in your database environment. You can debug the generated SQL by using console.log(teamWithFollowerCount.getQuery()) right before executing the query.